# Как передать строку в качестве агрумента функции main?

Tags: c++

```
int main()

{
cout << "Введите число любой длины" << endl;
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы она передавалась аргументом функции main. То есть получается можно было запустить программу с этим аргументом и она сразу могла работать дальше

Comment: `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`
`if(argc>1) s = argv[1];`

Answer (score 2):

При запуске

`your-program "This is a long string parameter"`

она получит "This is a long string parameter" в переменной argv[1]